Why is the position of the circles incorrect?
I am trying to use PyQt6 to design a program that draws a red circle at the position where the user clicks. However, when I click on the image in the window, the circle is not drawn exactly where I clicked; it is offset to the top and left of the clicked position. Additionally, I set up a list of the positions of the circles, but they are also not in the right place.
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QColor
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from Ui_dog import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.result = ''
        self.bind()
        self.setup_image()
        self.seted_circle = 2
        self.circles_list = [(125, 410), (347, 284), (152, 674), (467, 637), (218, 233), (316, 249)]
        
        # Initialize variables to store coordinates
        self.click_x = None
        self.click_y = None

    def bind(self):
        self.Btn_Quit.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def setup_image(self):
        # Load the image and set it to the QLabel
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("Puppies.jpg")
        self.dog_image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.dog_image.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.dog_image.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            if self.dog_image.underMouse():
                # Calculate click position relative to dog_image
                label_pos = event.position().toPoint() - self.dog_image.pos()
                self.click_x = label_pos.x()
                self.click_y = label_pos.y()
                print(f"Mouse clicked at: x={self.click_x}, y={self.click_y}")
                self.update_image()  # Update the image with the circle

    def update_image(self):
        if self.click_x is not None and self.click_y is not None:
            # Create a new pixmap to draw on
            pixmap = self.pixmap.copy()
            painter = QPainter(pixmap)
            
            # Drawing click position for debugging
            painter.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255))  # Red color
            painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255))  # Red color
            painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(self.click_x, self.click_y), 10, 10)  # Draw red circle at click position
            
            for i in range(len(self.circles_list)):
                x, y = self.circles_list[i]
                if i < self.seted_circle:
                    painter.setPen(QColor(0, 255, 0, 100))  # Green color using RGB values
                    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 100))  # Green color using RGB values
                elif i == self.seted_circle:
                    painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 0, 100))  # Yellow color using RGB values
                    painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0, 100))  # Yellow color using RGB values
                else:
                    painter.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 255, 100))  # Blue color using RGB values
                    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255, 100))  # Blue color using RGB values
                painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(x, y), 10, 10)  # Draw circle
            
            painter.end()

            # Update the QLabel with the modified pixmap
            self.dog_image.setPixmap(pixmap)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()




I tried to change the x and y values, but after making those adjustments, the blue, yellow, and green circles disappeared.
            for i in range(len(self.circles_list)):
                x, y = self.circles_list[i]
                if i < self.seted_circle:
                    painter.setPen(QColor(0, 255, 0, 100))  # Green color using RGB values
                    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 100))  # Green color using RGB values
                elif i == self.seted_circle:
                    painter.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 0, 100))  # Yellow color using RGB values
                    painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0, 100))  # Yellow color using RGB values
                else:
                    painter.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 255, 100))  # Blue color using RGB values
                    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255, 100))  # Blue color using RGB values
                painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(round(x*5.43), round(y*5.355)), 10, 10)  # Draw circle



However, when I click on the image label -- I don't know what you mean by that.  What label?  Does the dot appear where you click?  You need to figure out whether the position reported by mousePressEvent.position() is relative to the upper left of the whole window, or the upper left of the drawing (client) region.  That's not always obvious.

Mouse events are always relative to the widget that implements their handlers (with the exception of QAbstractScrollArea subclasses, but that's another story). If you implement mousePressEvent in the main window, then you're receiving events in the coordinate system of that window, not that of the dog_image widget. Using self.dog_image.pos() is inappropriate, as the widget position is always relative to its parent, not the window. You need to implement mouse event and painting in the widget that actually shows the pixmap and the circles, but if you also use QLabel alignment, you must »

» consider that, since the pixmap may be shown at a different position based on the origin point of the widget (0, 0). So, after getting the actual position within the widget, you need to map that position based on the label alignment: for instance, if the image is shown aligned to the bottom edge of the label geometry, you need to translate the position by considering the pixmap size and the difference with its height and the label height. These are all basic aspects of Euclidean space, if you're not familiar with them I strongly suggest you to take your time in doing proper research, as »

» they're used in almost any common UI/graphical toolkit. Finally, if you don't know how to properly implement event handlers in a child widget created in Designer, do some further research about widget promotion (when using subclasses), or event filtering (if avoiding a subclass is properly justified).
